# best way to find two number in an array which their sum be a specific number

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is the best algorithm to find two numbers in an array which their sum be a specific number ? for example `Array = [1,5,73,68,2]`  and specific number is 70 . output must be 68 + 2 = 70

Comment: Hi Ehsan. What do you mean by 'best algorithm' in this context - Easiest to implement, the most efficient performance-wise etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you want a better solution with better time complexity you can reach O(n) instead of O(n^2) and iterating the array only once.
but you need a data structure that has O(1) for finding data, something like hashmap.
and code would be like this:

```
function find(array, sum){
let answer = {}
for(const num of array){
    if(answer[num]){
        return { first: sum - num, second: num}
    }
    answer[sum - num] = true
}
return false
}

let arr = [ 2, 5, 7, 3, 82]

console.log(find( arr, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
    function example(){

     var numbersArray = ['1','5','73','68','2'];
    var number = 70;

    for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < numbersArray.length; j++) {
        if(Number(numbersArray[i])+Number(numbersArray[j]) == number){
      console.log('found this:'+numbersArray[i]+'+'+numbersArray[j] +'='+number)
      }  
    }
    }
    }
    example();
```

Ofcourse you dont have to use `console.log` , this is just an example.
A simple example , i'm pretty sure there are another ways to do it.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I do my try, hope this helps.

```js
function getPairs(arr, n, sum) 
{    let temp = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum) 
                temp.push([arr[i],arr[j]])
    return temp
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(getPairs(arr, arr.length, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop

```js
 sums=[]
    function findinarray(specialnumb){
    array = [1,5,73,68,2]
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){   
      for(let j=1+i;j<array.length;j++){
      o=array[i]
      b=array[j]
        if(o+b==specialnumb)
        sums.push(o,b)   
      }
     }
     return sums
    } 
    console.log(findinarray(70))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Working solution. Just run snippet to see in action.

You can pass `array()` to this function and total number you want to count in that `array`. In return it will `console.log` the indexes totaling that number which you wanted.

```js
function checkSum(arrayValues, total) {
  var map = [];
  var indexxxx = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < arrayValues.length; x++) {
    if (map[arrayValues[x]] != null) {
      var index = map[arrayValues[x]];
      indexxxx[0] = index;
      indexxxx[1] = x;
      break;
    } else {
      map[total - arrayValues[x]] = x;
    }
  }
  console.log('Array Index at ' + indexxxx[0] + ' & ' + indexxxx[1] + ' sums equals to ' + total)
}

checkSum([1, 5, 73, 68, 2], 70)
```

If you want to know the exact value totalling the number then you do this:

```js
function checkSum(arrayValues, total) {
  var indexxxx = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arrayValues.length; x++) {
    for (var j = 1 + x; j < arrayValues.length; j++) {
      o = arrayValues[x]
      b = arrayValues[j]
      if (o + b == total)
        indexxxx.push(o, b)
    }
  }

  console.log('Array value at ' + indexxxx[0] + ' & ' + indexxxx[1] + ' sums equals to ' + total)
}

checkSum([1, 5, 73, 68, 2], 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created this utility in order to find the pairs whose sum will be equal to the provided/expected sum. Here I have not used nested loops. This will also eliminate duplicate pairs.

```js
getPairs = (array, sum) => {
  const obj = {}
  const finalResult = []
  array.forEach(d => {
    obj[sum - d] = d
  })

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[sum - key]) {
      finalResult.push([parseInt(key), sum - key])
      delete obj[key]
    }
  })
  return finalResult
}

const array = [1, 5, 73, 68, 2, 4, 74]
const sum = 78

console.log(getPairs(array, sum))
```

Hope this helps.